# How to display only few languages liferay language portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

```
In Language portlet I want to display only few language. Is it possible?
I have tried portal-ext.properties and added locale properties like below.
and I want to display language in combobox please provide solution.
```

I want to display below languages. I am new in liferay. I am using liferay comunity version 6.2.
   I don't want to add any extra language or locale.

```
locales=en_US,de_DE

I have deleted database and create database and start again server. It show all the language.

My portal-ext.properties look like below.Please help me out.

jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/liferay62?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=root
locales=en_US,de_DE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to change anything in `portal-ext.properties`. Just go to *Control Panel* -> *Portal Settings* and choose *Display Settings* from right menu. Then limit the *Current* list in *Available Languages* section, save your changes and you are done.

Just note that this setting will limit langages not only for Language portlet, but for whole portal.

Comment: ...and if you want to configure through portal-ext.properties, use `locales.enabled`

Comment: I have done It with on Language portlet -> click on top right options -> Configuration -> setup -> Languages -> remove the languages from current to available. It works. For dropdown I select Display Style  -> Select box  Thanks for answers. Thanks Olaf for alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

> "There's one caveat: If you've ever set this configuration through the
>   UI (in ControlPanel -> Portal Settings -> Display Settings), they will
>   be stored in the database and override what you configure in
>   portal-ext.properties. Thus, you might want to check what you find in
>   Control Panel and might need to configure there instead of
>   portal-ext.properties.

Source: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/45421596